Flutter connectivity plus error while am running my app on emulator after changing environment from macos to window
I have been changing environment from macos to window but am facing this error
Execution failed for task ':connectivity_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':connectivity_plus:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\dilua\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\dilua.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ca0f03754238ee726b2ce160ba08b7a8\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\dilua.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ca0f03754238ee726b2ce160ba08b7a8\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.Run with --scan to get full insights.Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.  here is my dependency dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
injectable: ^2.3.5
nb_utils: any
get: ^4.6.6
google_fonts: ^6.2.1
flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
dartz: ^0.10.1
image_picker: ^1.1.2
art_sweetalert: ^0.0.5
file_picker: ^8.0.5
flutter_downloader: ^1.11.8
localstorage: ^5.0.0
get_storage: ^2.1.1
http: ^1.2.2
pinput: ^5.0.0
sms_autofill: ^2.4.0
intl: ^0.19.0
sqflite: ^2.3.3+1
path: ^1.9.0
percent_indicator: ^4.2.3
flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.1
url_launcher: ^6.3.0

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_lints: ^5.0.0
build_runner: ^2.4.9
change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
injectable_generator: ^2.5.1
freezed: ^2.4.8
am trying to run my project on emulator

check which java version you are using in macos, this is because java version mismatch. I had same error with latest android studio build. if you have the mentioned issue then try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/79102143/8764293
